# non-deterministic behavior of int subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, subclass, built-in

I have subclassed `int` to add an extra attribute:

```
class Integer(int):
    def __new__(cls, value, base=10, indirect=False):
        try:
            obj = int.__new__(cls, value, base)
        except TypeError:
            obj = int.__new__(cls, value)
        return obj

    def __init__(self, value, base=10, indirect=False):
        self.indirect = indirect
```

Using this class in my application, `int(Integer(b'0'))` **sometimes** returns a value of 48 (= `ord('0')`!) or 192, instead of the correct value 0. `str(Integer(b'0'))` always returns `'0'`. This seems to only occur for the value 0. First decoding `b'0'` to a string, or passing `int(b'0')` to `Integer` makes no difference. The problem lies with converting an `Integer(0)` to an `int` with `int()`.

Furthermore, this occurs in a random way. Subsequent runs will produce 48 or 192 at different points in the application (a parser). Both Python 3.2.2 and 3.2.3 behave the same (32-bit, Windows XP).

I cannot seem to reproduce this in a simple test program. The following produces no output:

```
for i in range(100000):
    integer = int(Integer(b'0'))
    if integer > 0:
        print(integer)
```

Checking for the condition `int(Integer()) > 0` in my application (when I know the argument to `Integer` is `b'0'`) and conditionally printing `int(Integer(b'0'))` a number of times, the results 48 and 192 do show up now and then.

So, what's going on?

**EDIT** - As I can't reproduce the problem in a short test program, I have made the relevant code available [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22669353/pdf.py). It is basically a PDF parser. The output for [this PDF file](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/math-support/vieth2008.pdf) produces, for example:

```
b'0' 0 Integer(0) 192 0 b'0' 16853712
b'0' 0 Integer(0) 48 0 b'0' 16938088
b'0' 0 Integer(0) 192 0 b'0' 17421696
b'0' 0 Integer(0) 48 0 b'0' 23144888
b'0' 0 Integer(0) 48 0 b'0' 23185408
b'0' 0 Integer(0) 48 0 b'0' 23323272
```

Search for print function calls in the code to see what this represents.

Comment: Have you tried examining the contents of the parameters coming into the `__new__` or `__init__` methods? I get the same results you do for the second snippet of code. What this leads me to believe is that those methods are not being passed the parameter values you think they are being passed, and that your actual bug may lie elsewhere.

Comment: For the record, I ran your code with `xrange(1000000000)` and didn't see a single Integer above 0...

Comment: @seggy I have checked now and `__new__` actually gets passed `b'0'`. The application indeed causes the problem somehow. But I can't imagine how. I'm thinking maybe it's corrupting memory, but I suppose that's unlikely in Python?

Comment: Are you calling ord(b'0') at any point in your parser and potentially passing the result of that function? It's hard to tell without the context of the code that makes use of this.

Comment: My coworker and I just tried to reproduce this on Python-3.2.3 64-bit on Windows 7 from your source code and test data, and cannot get it to happen at all.  Ran it on Python-3.2.3 32-bit on the same box, and it happened right away.  Still no idea why, but I hope that narrows it down.

Comment: Shouldn't you be also calling: int.__init__() in your __init__ ?

Comment: @mayhewr and coworker: Thanks for checking. I guess it must be a Python bug then. I have created a ticket (http://bugs.python.org/issue14630).

Comment: Indeed, it is a Python bug.  Many thanks for reporting it!  We're working on a fix. :-)

Comment: @BrechtMachiels: Answer it by yourself that python.org is working on it and they have a patch. Accept your answer to be the question closed.

Comment: BTW, I disagree with the closure of this question as too localized.  It's relevant at least between now and the next bugfix release of Python 3.2 (probably many months away), and probably beyond that for people who don't happen to have the latest and greatest Python installed.